# Path configuration for testing Ember-electron with Spectron

Tags: ember.js, electron, spectron

I am trying to integrate Spectron with Ember-electron for testing.

I found an [example](https://github.com/jwood803/ElectronSpectronDemo/blob/master/tests/test.js) for Spectron but I am not sure what to assign in the `electronPath` part in case of Ember-electron.

I do not have an .exe or .cmd how to point to the location of the application in the test folder.

```
beforeEach(function () {
return helpers.startApplication({

  args:[path.join(__dirname, '..')] //**
}).then(function (startedApp) { app = startedApp })
})
```

Comment: Check: https://github.com/felixrieseberg/ember-electron/issues/304#issuecomment-325561286